# using class level variable in class which handle multiple request

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have a class as written as follows, method `doSomethingForMe()` of which gets called from a servlet. The servlet can issue multiple request for the same method. 
The Servlet gets the object from Spring. As this class is getting initialized by Spring Bean factory.

```
public class ClassLevelVariableTest
{
  private List<String> errorLists;

   public void doSomethingForMe()
   {
     errorLists = new ArrayList<>();
     // plus do the rest functionality
     if (!errorLists.isEmpty())
      {
        prepareErrorList(errorLists);
      }
   }

  private void prepareErrorList(List<String> errorLists)
  {
    for (String errorString : errorLists)
    {
      System.out.println(errorString);
    }
  }
}
```

So my first query is: Is there a chance of getting the same object of `errorLists` variable in subsequent requests?

Is there a chance of getting the variable overridden by second request?

Comment: No there are no chances , As you are creating `new Object of ArrayList` each time the method is called !!

Comment: You must be creating a new object of this class in servlet, right? How will it affect `errorList` variable if there is a new object everytime?

Comment: I am using the spring too. So the class  ClassLevelVariableTest is a spring bean. So there won;t be a new operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bean is instantiated for every request then no, you are fine.  If Spring injects a single one reused for every request then you have a problem.  You can fix this easily by not storing errorLists as an instance variable.  Change your code to this:

```
public class ClassLevelVariableTest
{

    public void doSomethingForMe()
    {
         List<String> errorLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

It doesn't seem like you're using errorLists as an instance variable so you should be fine.

Comment: ** If Spring injects a single one reused for every request then you have a problem.**. How we can confirm this?

Comment: I don't use Spring anymore so not sure on the best way, but you could just put a print statement in the constructor and see if it gets constructed more than once

Comment: I found it my self. The scope of bean can be defined in application context.  The default one is Singleton. Hence in my case it will create a single object per application.